# PostGIS. Obtain the rotation between two equal Geometries

Tags: postgis, geometry

I've got two features with the same drawing (poliline) but one is rotated relative to the other. I would like no know in PostGIS the rotation between the two geometries to apply this rotation to a third geometry (poliline).

I know how to do the last step with the st_rotate function but i don't know how to do the first one.

Regards,

Comment: A rotation (plus a translation, of course) is determined by its effect on two distinct points. One way to obtain three *corresponding* points among two polylines is to compute their endpoints and their centroid. Usually the three will not coincide. You know the centroids correspond, leaving only two possibilities for matching the endpoints: one of those will work.